# SQL Server 2005 'INSTEAD OF' DELETE Trigger - Not deleting Source Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-trigger

I created a trigger in SQL Server 2005 that inserts records into a history table whenever a deletion occurs in the source table. The records are getting inserted, but they are not getting deleted from the source table.

Here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_EdiHistory 
ON  dbo.EDI10000 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.EDI10500 ON;

    INSERT INTO EDI10500(File_Id, Tp_Id, File_Name, File_Size, File_Data, Rec_Date, Content_Type, Update_Flag)
       SELECT 
          File_Id, Tp_Id, File_Name, File_Size, File_Data,
          Rec_Date, Content_Type, Update_Flag
       FROM 
          DELETED   
END
GO
```

I had to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger because my tables contains `Image` type columns.

Please if anyone has any idea why this is happening.

Thank you.

*** UPDATE ***

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_EdiHistory 
ON  dbo.EDI10000 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.EDI10500 ON;

    INSERT INTO EDI10500 ([File_Id],Tp_Id,[File_Name],File_Size
                            ,File_Data,Rec_Date,Content_Type,Update_Flag)
    SELECT   [File_Id], Tp_Id, [File_Name], File_Size, File_Data,
          Rec_Date, Content_Type, Update_Flag
    FROM DELETED    

    DELETE FROM dbo.EDI10000
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM DELETED
                  WHERE [FILE_ID] = dbo.EDI10000.[File_Id])

END
GO
```

Comment: Well, what would you expect something called "INSTEAD OF DELETE" to do, exactly?

Comment: You need an `AFTER DELETE Trigger` here. The rest should be fine.

Comment: Why are you using the image datatype? It has been deprecated since 2005. Use varbinary(max) instead.

Comment: Cant use an AFTER DELETE trigger with an Image datatype. And can't change to varbinary(MAX) because its SQL 2005. Tried to change it to varbinary(MAX) but won't allow me.

Comment: @hmakled: SQL Server 2005 **DOES** support `VARBINARY(MAX)` .... how did you try to change the datatype to `VARBINARY(MAX)`, and what exactly happened?

Comment: @M.Ali I added a comment to your answer regarding the DELETE statement within the INSTEAD OF Trigger. Can you please answer it when you get a chance? Thank you

Comment: @M.Ali Well I added the brackets as you did and still no luck. Still won't delete record.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Triggers , fire Instead of the triggering action. In your Case this instead of Trigger fires and Inserts data into your history table.

Note this trigger fires instead of the Delete command. So if you also want to Delete rows you will need to add Delete statement inside this trigger.

Having said this I think instead of `Instead Trigger` if you simply define an `After Trigger` with same definition as your this instead of trigger will makes things pretty simple. It will delete the rows from table and then insert rows into your history table as you are expecting it to work.

### Update

Since you have mentioned you cannot use Image Data type inside an `After Trigger` in sql server 2005, I am not aware of this limitation. Well in this case you can simply add a delete statement inside your this existing instead of trigger.

```
DELETE FROM dbo.table
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM deleted 
              WHERE Pk_Column = table.PK_Column)
```

Comment: I tried the After Trigger and I get an error because my table has an Image datatype which cannot be used with an After Trigger in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: hmmm... not to sure about this limitation but anyway just simply add the delete statement inside your trigger definition.

Comment: how would I add the Delete statement inside my trigger? Not sure how. Do I just do DELETE FROM dbo.table?

Comment: This is what I added and its still not deleting: DELETE FROM dbo.EDI10000
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
          FROM DELETED 
          WHERE File_Id = EDI10000.File_Id)

Comment: Mr Ali did you see my last response? Did I do it correctly cause its not deleting. I added this delete statement at the very end after my "SELECT (.....) FROM DELETED" statement.

Comment: Update your Question with whatever code you are using currently.

Comment: I have just edited your question try this... I cannot see anything wrong with this code except that some column names are key words, I have put square brackets around them, the rest looks just fine.

Comment: Yes one of my columns is name File_Id. Is that going to be an issue? Are you saying to put the brackets around it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of delete replaces the standard action of the DELETE statement.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191208(v=sql.105).aspx

Have a look here how to do what you really want:
[How to create a before delete trigger in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10443829/532498)