# Is there a DELETED table in Rails just as in SQL Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, triggers, delete-row

I need to be able to do the same as demonstrated below in my rails app. As you can see, in SQL server there is a table called DELETED that stores those rows that were just deleted. source: [How to create a before delete trigger in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443829/how-to-create-a-before-delete-trigger-in-sql-server)

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_AUD_DEL
ON yourTable
FOR DELETE
AS
     INSERT INTO my_audit_table  (col1, col2, ...)
     SELECT col1, col2...
     FROM DELETED
```

Applying this logic to rails, is there such a table/location to call from to get those rows just as they are deleted in rails? I am aware of the callback before/after_destroy but how can you access that information that is being destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

Relying on database-specific behavior is not what ActiveRecord is about. It solely uses an RDBMS as a form of persistent storage. Data processing, such as this, is delegated to the app code.

ActiveRecord principles state that each row in the database is an instance of a model class in your app. Therefore, a callback is called on an instance of a model to be destroyed shortly.

Before a model is destroyed (`before_destroy`) your data should be accessible through class fields inside that callback. So you should be able to place this callback into one of your models you wish to keep track of:

```
def log_to_history
  DeletedStuff.create(
      title: "Something number #{id}",
      deleted_at: Time.now,
      content: self.to_yaml
    )
end

before_delete :log_to_history
```

It is a somewhat weird example that allows to store just about any deleted item (even different models' instances) in the same table, attributes are serialized with YAML. But I did my best to expose data structure, so it can be easily altered to suit your needs.

This example would require a `DeletedStuff` model with fields

- `title: string`
- `deleted_at:time`
- `content:text`

Comment: Is there a way to do this but with a temp table in rails?

Comment: @Sauron What do you mean "temp table"? It depends on what do you want to achieve.

Comment: How can you get just the record that is being deleted? I am looking to get the id of the record that is being destroyed and tried `@deleted_row = self.where(campaign_id: :id)` inside of the method called at before_destroy but nothing returned.

Comment: @Sauron callback method is executed in context of an object being deleted. By that I mean, it's `self`.

Comment: then how can I get the object being deleted. Then can I just use the syntax `@deleted_row = self`?

Comment: @Sauron Yes, but you'd assign a to-be-deleted object a certain field. It will vanish after the callback is done. Why would you do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62073/discussion-between-sauron-and-d-side).

Comment: I'm building a pretty complicated relationship, where I need to have one row removed from a table after the removal of a row in another table

Comment: @Sauron Then you failed to specify what are you trying to solve. I'm merely answering the given question, not solving anything.