# Move Data to Another Table when Deleted

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

How to move the data from "Detail" table to "LogDetail" when users deleted the data from "Detail" ?

Im using EF 6, MVC 5, and DB First method

Delete Action from Controller

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(MyViewModel model)
        {
            DetailPengiriman detailPengiriman = db.DetailPengirimen.Find(model.TransID);
            db.DetailPengirimen.Remove(detailPengiriman); 

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { compID = model.compID });
        }
```

Can I use trigger from SQL Server and how to do it ? Thank You

Comment: Have a look at [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443829/how-to-create-a-before-delete-trigger-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thank You very much! But how to implement it to my DB First MVC?

Comment: Just expand your table `Detail`. There is a folder called `Triggers` just right click at this folder and then click *new Trigger*

Comment: Oh I see, so I only need to create new trigger and do nothing to my controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a `for delete trigger`

```
CREATE TRIGGER <trigger_name>
ON Detail
FOR DELETE
AS
     INSERT INTO LogDetail  <column_list>
     SELECT <column_list>
     FROM DELETED
```

Comment: Thank you once again, but how to implement it to DB First MVC

Comment: Just run this code, after replacing `<trigger_name>` and `<column_list>` as appropriate and then execute in the DB which contains the `Detail` table