# How to UPDATE modified and deleted entities on SaveContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

Goal is to track who had changed and deleted an entity.

So I have an entity that implements an interface:

```
interface IAuditable {
   string ModifiedBy {get;set;}
}

class User: IAuditable {
   public int UserId {get;set;}
   public string UserName {get;set;}
   public string ModifiedBy {get;set;}
   [Timestamp]
   public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Now the code of entity remove operation could look like this :

```
User user = context.Users.First();
user.ModifiedBy = CurrentUser.Name;
context.Users.Remove(employer);
context.SaveContext();
```

In real: `ModifiedBy` **update will be never executed** (when my db history triggers expect to "handle" it). **Only delete statement will be executed** on DB.

I want to know how to force EF Core "update" deleted entities/entries (which implements the specific interface) if entity was modified.

Note:  `RowVersion` adds additional complexity.

P.S.
To put additional SaveContext call manually - of course is an option, but I would like to have a generic solution: many various updates and deletes, then one SaveContext do all analyzes.

To update those properties manually before SaveContext collecting `var deletedEntries = entries.Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted && isAuditable(e))` it is not an option since it can ruin EF Core locks order management and therefore provoke deadlocks.

Most clear solution would be just stay with one SaveContext call but inject UPDATE statement on auditable fields just before `EF CORE` call `DELETE`. How to achieve this? May be somebody has the solution already?

Alternative could be "on delete do not compose DELETE statement but call stored procedure that can accept auditable fields as paramaters"

Comment: Have you come across the following in your research  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443829/how-to-create-a-before-delete-trigger-in-sql-server#10443862

Comment: triggers are not the case: I need to force EF Core compose "UPDATE statement together with DELETE"  and push audit information to the table (to trace who had deleted an entity)..

Comment: The difficulty is that an entity always has one state when it comes to `SaveChanges`. Any state changed it has gone through before that are lost. Deleted is deleted. Even the `IsModified` state of properties is erased. You only chance (to let EF handle this) is to introduce soft deletes.

Comment: That is true, but somewhere we have DELETE statement composition. And I hope there it should be possible to insert UPDATE before DELETE...

Comment: @Gert You will be surprised (pleasantly I hope) how many things can be done in EF Core which were virtually impossible in EF6 :)

Comment: @Ivan Surprised? Amazed! We can only hope that this will turn into a stable public API. Too bad that in my daily work on projects I'm stuck with EF6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to know how to inject my "UPDATE statement" just before EF call its "DELETE statement"? Do we have such API?

Interesting question. At the time of writing (EF Core 2.1.3), there is no such **public** API. The following solution is based on the internal APIs, which  in EF Core fortunately are publicly accessible under the typical internal API disclaimer:

> This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.

Now the solution. The service responsible for modification command creation is called [`ICommandBatchPreparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.update.icommandbatchpreparer?view=efcore-2.1):

> A service for preparing a list of [ModificationCommandBatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.update.modificationcommandbatch?view=efcore-2.1)s for the entities represented by the given list of [IUpdateEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.update.iupdateentry?view=efcore-2.1)s.

It contains a single method called [`BatchCommands`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.update.icommandbatchpreparer.batchcommands?view=efcore-2.1):

> Creates the command batches needed to insert/update/delete the entities represented by the given list of [IUpdateEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.update.iupdateentry?view=efcore-2.1)s.

with the following signature:

```
public IEnumerable<ModificationCommandBatch> BatchCommands(
    IReadOnlyList<IUpdateEntry> entries);
```

and default implementation in [`CommandBatchPreparer`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.2/src/EFCore.Relational/Update/Internal/CommandBatchPreparer.cs) class.

We will replace that service with custom implementation which will extend the list with "modified" entries and use the base implementation to do the actual job. Since batch is basically a lists of modification commands sorted by dependency and then *by type* with `Delete` being before `Update`, we will use separate batch(es) for the update commands first and concatenate the rest after.

The generated modification commands are based on [`IUpdateEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.update.iupdateentry?view=efcore-2.1):

> The information passed to a database provider to save changes to an entity to the database.

Luckily it's an interface, so we will provide our own implementation for the additional "modified" entries, as well as for their corresponding delete entries (more on that later).

First we'll create a base implementation which simply delegates the calls to the underlying object, thus allowing us to override later only the methods that are essential for what we are trying to achieve:

```
class DelegatingEntry : IUpdateEntry
{
    public DelegatingEntry(IUpdateEntry source) { Source = source; }
    public IUpdateEntry Source { get; }
    public virtual IEntityType EntityType => Source.EntityType;
    public virtual EntityState EntityState => Source.EntityState;
    public virtual IUpdateEntry SharedIdentityEntry => Source.SharedIdentityEntry;
    public virtual object GetCurrentValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase) => Source.GetCurrentValue(propertyBase);
    public virtual TProperty GetCurrentValue<TProperty>(IPropertyBase propertyBase) => Source.GetCurrentValue<TProperty>(propertyBase);
    public virtual object GetOriginalValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase) => Source.GetOriginalValue(propertyBase);
    public virtual TProperty GetOriginalValue<TProperty>(IProperty property) => Source.GetOriginalValue<TProperty>(property);
    public virtual bool HasTemporaryValue(IProperty property) => Source.HasTemporaryValue(property);
    public virtual bool IsModified(IProperty property) => Source.IsModified(property);
    public virtual bool IsStoreGenerated(IProperty property) => Source.IsStoreGenerated(property);
    public virtual void SetCurrentValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase, object value) => Source.SetCurrentValue(propertyBase, value);
    public virtual EntityEntry ToEntityEntry() => Source.ToEntityEntry();
}
```

Now the first custom entry:

```
class AuditUpdateEntry : DelegatingEntry
{
    public AuditUpdateEntry(IUpdateEntry source) : base(source) { }
    public override EntityState EntityState => EntityState.Modified;
    public override bool IsModified(IProperty property)
    {
        if (property.Name == nameof(IAuditable.ModifiedBy)) return true;
        return false;
    }
    public override bool IsStoreGenerated(IProperty property)
        => property.ValueGenerated.ForUpdate()
            && (property.AfterSaveBehavior == PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore
                || !IsModified(property));
}
```

First we "modify" the source state from `Deleted` to `Modified`. Then we modify the `IsModified` method which returns `false` for `Deleted` entries to return `true` for the auditable properties, thus forcing them to be included in the update command. Finally we modify the `IsStoreGenerated` method which also returns `false` for `Deleted` entries to return the corresponding result for the `Modified` entries ([EF Core code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.2/src/EFCore/ChangeTracking/Internal/InternalEntityEntry.cs#L1146)). This is needed to let EF Core correctly handle the database generated values on update like `RowVersion`. After executing the command, EF Core will call `SetCurrentValue` with the values returned from the database. Which does not happen for normal `Deleted` entries and for normal `Modified` entries propagates to their entity.

Which leads us to the need of the second custom entry, which will wrap the original entry and also will be used as source for the `AuditUpdateEntry`, hence will receive the `SetCurrentValue` from it. It will store the received values internally, thus keeping the original entity state unchanged, and will treat them as both "current" and "original". This is essential because the delete command will be executed after update, and if the `RowVersion` does not return the new value as "original", the generated delete command will fail.

Here is the implementation:

```
class AuditDeleteEntry : DelegatingEntry
{
    public AuditDeleteEntry(IUpdateEntry source) : base(source) { }
    Dictionary<IPropertyBase, object> updatedValues;
    public override object GetCurrentValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase)
    {
        if (updatedValues != null && updatedValues.TryGetValue(propertyBase, out var value))
            return value;
        return base.GetCurrentValue(propertyBase);
    }
    public override object GetOriginalValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase)
    {
        if (updatedValues != null && updatedValues.TryGetValue(propertyBase, out var value))
            return value;
        return base.GetOriginalValue(propertyBase);
    }
    public override void SetCurrentValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase, object value)
    {
        if (updatedValues == null) updatedValues = new Dictionary<IPropertyBase, object>();
        updatedValues[propertyBase] = value;
    }
}
```

With these two custom entries we are ready to implement our custom command batch builder:

```
class AuditableCommandBatchPreparer : CommandBatchPreparer
{
    public AuditableCommandBatchPreparer(CommandBatchPreparerDependencies dependencies) : base(dependencies) { }

    public override IEnumerable<ModificationCommandBatch> BatchCommands(IReadOnlyList<IUpdateEntry> entries)
    {
        List<IUpdateEntry> auditEntries = null;
        List<AuditUpdateEntry> auditUpdateEntries = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.Count; i++)
        {
            var entry = entries[i];
            if (entry.EntityState == EntityState.Deleted && typeof(IAuditable).IsAssignableFrom(entry.EntityType.ClrType))
            {
                if (auditEntries == null)
                {
                    auditEntries = entries.Take(i).ToList();
                    auditUpdateEntries = new List<AuditUpdateEntry>();
                }
                var deleteEntry = new AuditDeleteEntry(entry);
                var updateEntry = new AuditUpdateEntry(deleteEntry);
                auditEntries.Add(deleteEntry);
                auditUpdateEntries.Add(updateEntry);
            }
            else
            {
                auditEntries?.Add(entry);
            }
        }
        return auditEntries != null ?
            base.BatchCommands(auditUpdateEntries).Concat(base.BatchCommands(auditEntries)) :
            base.BatchCommands(entries);
    }
}
```

and we are almost done. Add a helper method for registering our service(s):

```
public static class AuditableExtensions
{
    public static DbContextOptionsBuilder AddAudit(this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<ICommandBatchPreparer, AuditableCommandBatchPreparer>();
        return optionsBuilder;
    }
}
```

and call it from you `DbContext` derived class `OnConfiguring` override:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    // ...
    optionsBuilder.AddAudit();
}
```

and you are done.

All this is for single auditable field populated manually just to get the idea. It can be extended with more auditable fields, registering a custom auditable fields provider service and automatically filling the values for insert/update/delete operations etc.

---

**P.S.** Full code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal;
using Auditable.Internal; 

namespace Auditable
{
    public interface IAuditable
    {
        string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }

    public static class AuditableExtensions
    {
        public static DbContextOptionsBuilder AddAudit(this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<ICommandBatchPreparer, AuditableCommandBatchPreparer>();
            return optionsBuilder;
        }
    }
}

namespace Auditable.Internal
{
    class AuditableCommandBatchPreparer : CommandBatchPreparer
    {
        public AuditableCommandBatchPreparer(CommandBatchPreparerDependencies dependencies) : base(dependencies) { }

        public override IEnumerable<ModificationCommandBatch> BatchCommands(IReadOnlyList<IUpdateEntry> entries)
        {
            List<IUpdateEntry> auditEntries = null;
            List<AuditUpdateEntry> auditUpdateEntries = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < entries.Count; i++)
            {
                var entry = entries[i];
                if (entry.EntityState == EntityState.Deleted && typeof(IAuditable).IsAssignableFrom(entry.EntityType.ClrType))
                {
                    if (auditEntries == null)
                    {
                        auditEntries = entries.Take(i).ToList();
                        auditUpdateEntries = new List<AuditUpdateEntry>();
                    }
                    var deleteEntry = new AuditDeleteEntry(entry);
                    var updateEntry = new AuditUpdateEntry(deleteEntry);
                    auditEntries.Add(deleteEntry);
                    auditUpdateEntries.Add(updateEntry);
                }
                else
                {
                    auditEntries?.Add(entry);
                }
            }
            return auditEntries != null ?
                base.BatchCommands(auditUpdateEntries).Concat(base.BatchCommands(auditEntries)) :
                base.BatchCommands(entries);
        }
    }

    class AuditUpdateEntry : DelegatingEntry
    {
        public AuditUpdateEntry(IUpdateEntry source) : base(source) { }
        public override EntityState EntityState => EntityState.Modified;
        public override bool IsModified(IProperty property)
        {
            if (property.Name == nameof(IAuditable.ModifiedBy)) return true;
            return false;
        }
        public override bool IsStoreGenerated(IProperty property)
            => property.ValueGenerated.ForUpdate()
                && (property.AfterSaveBehavior == PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore
                    || !IsModified(property));
    }

    class AuditDeleteEntry : DelegatingEntry
    {
        public AuditDeleteEntry(IUpdateEntry source) : base(source) { }
        Dictionary<IPropertyBase, object> updatedValues;
        public override object GetCurrentValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase)
        {
            if (updatedValues != null && updatedValues.TryGetValue(propertyBase, out var value))
                return value;
            return base.GetCurrentValue(propertyBase);
        }
        public override object GetOriginalValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase)
        {
            if (updatedValues != null && updatedValues.TryGetValue(propertyBase, out var value))
                return value;
            return base.GetOriginalValue(propertyBase);
        }
        public override void SetCurrentValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase, object value)
        {
            if (updatedValues == null) updatedValues = new Dictionary<IPropertyBase, object>();
            updatedValues[propertyBase] = value;
        }
    }

    class DelegatingEntry : IUpdateEntry
    {
        public DelegatingEntry(IUpdateEntry source) { Source = source; }
        public IUpdateEntry Source { get; }
        public virtual IEntityType EntityType => Source.EntityType;
        public virtual EntityState EntityState => Source.EntityState;
        public virtual IUpdateEntry SharedIdentityEntry => Source.SharedIdentityEntry;
        public virtual object GetCurrentValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase) => Source.GetCurrentValue(propertyBase);
        public virtual TProperty GetCurrentValue<TProperty>(IPropertyBase propertyBase) => Source.GetCurrentValue<TProperty>(propertyBase);
        public virtual object GetOriginalValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase) => Source.GetOriginalValue(propertyBase);
        public virtual TProperty GetOriginalValue<TProperty>(IProperty property) => Source.GetOriginalValue<TProperty>(property);
        public virtual bool HasTemporaryValue(IProperty property) => Source.HasTemporaryValue(property);
        public virtual bool IsModified(IProperty property) => Source.IsModified(property);
        public virtual bool IsStoreGenerated(IProperty property) => Source.IsStoreGenerated(property);
        public virtual void SetCurrentValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase, object value) => Source.SetCurrentValue(propertyBase, value);
        public virtual EntityEntry ToEntityEntry() => Source.ToEntityEntry();
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** Full code updated for EF Core 5 (not tested):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal;
using Auditable.Internal;

namespace Auditable
{
    public interface IAuditable
    {
        string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }

    public static class AuditableExtensions
    {
        public static DbContextOptionsBuilder AddAudit(this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<ICommandBatchPreparer, AuditableCommandBatchPreparer>();
            return optionsBuilder;
        }
    }
}

namespace Auditable.Internal
{
    class AuditableCommandBatchPreparer : CommandBatchPreparer
    {
        public AuditableCommandBatchPreparer(CommandBatchPreparerDependencies dependencies) : base(dependencies) { }

        public override IEnumerable<ModificationCommandBatch> BatchCommands(IList<IUpdateEntry> entries, IUpdateAdapter updateAdapter)
        {
            List<IUpdateEntry> auditEntries = null;
            List<IUpdateEntry> auditUpdateEntries = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < entries.Count; i++)
            {
                var entry = entries[i];
                if (entry.EntityState == EntityState.Deleted && typeof(IAuditable).IsAssignableFrom(entry.EntityType.ClrType))
                {
                    if (auditEntries == null)
                    {
                        auditEntries = entries.Take(i).ToList();
                        auditUpdateEntries = new List<IUpdateEntry>();
                    }
                    var deleteEntry = new AuditDeleteEntry(entry);
                    var updateEntry = new AuditUpdateEntry(deleteEntry);
                    auditEntries.Add(deleteEntry);
                    auditUpdateEntries.Add(updateEntry);
                }
                else
                {
                    auditEntries?.Add(entry);
                }
            }
            return auditEntries != null ?
                base.BatchCommands(auditUpdateEntries, updateAdapter).Concat(base.BatchCommands(auditEntries, updateAdapter)) :
                base.BatchCommands(entries, updateAdapter);
        }
    }

    class AuditUpdateEntry : DelegatingEntry
    {
        public AuditUpdateEntry(IUpdateEntry source) : base(source) { }
        public override EntityState EntityState => EntityState.Modified;
        public override bool IsModified(IProperty property)
        {
            if (property.Name == nameof(IAuditable.ModifiedBy)) return true;
            return false;
        }
        public override bool IsStoreGenerated(IProperty property)
            => property.ValueGenerated.ForUpdate()
                && (property.GetAfterSaveBehavior() == PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore
                    || !IsModified(property));
    }

    class AuditDeleteEntry : DelegatingEntry
    {
        public AuditDeleteEntry(IUpdateEntry source) : base(source) { }
        Dictionary<IPropertyBase, object> updatedValues;
        public override object GetCurrentValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase)
        {
            if (updatedValues != null && updatedValues.TryGetValue(propertyBase, out var value))
                return value;
            return base.GetCurrentValue(propertyBase);
        }
        public override object GetOriginalValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase)
        {
            if (updatedValues != null && updatedValues.TryGetValue(propertyBase, out var value))
                return value;
            return base.GetOriginalValue(propertyBase);
        }
        public override void SetStoreGeneratedValue(IProperty property, object value)
        {
            if (updatedValues == null) updatedValues = new Dictionary<IPropertyBase, object>();
            updatedValues[property] = value;
        }
    }

    class DelegatingEntry : IUpdateEntry
    {
        public DelegatingEntry(IUpdateEntry source) { Source = source; }
        public IUpdateEntry Source { get; }
        public virtual IEntityType EntityType => Source.EntityType;
        public virtual EntityState EntityState { get => Source.EntityState; set => Source.EntityState = value; }
        public virtual IUpdateEntry SharedIdentityEntry => Source.SharedIdentityEntry;
        public virtual object GetCurrentValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase) => Source.GetCurrentValue(propertyBase);
        public virtual TProperty GetCurrentValue<TProperty>(IPropertyBase propertyBase) => Source.GetCurrentValue<TProperty>(propertyBase);
        public virtual object GetOriginalValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase) => Source.GetOriginalValue(propertyBase);
        public virtual TProperty GetOriginalValue<TProperty>(IProperty property) => Source.GetOriginalValue<TProperty>(property);
        public virtual object GetPreStoreGeneratedCurrentValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase) => Source.GetPreStoreGeneratedCurrentValue(propertyBase);
        public virtual object GetRelationshipSnapshotValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase) => Source.GetRelationshipSnapshotValue(propertyBase);
        public virtual bool HasTemporaryValue(IProperty property) => Source.HasTemporaryValue(property);
        public virtual bool IsConceptualNull(IProperty property) => Source.IsConceptualNull(property);
        public virtual bool IsModified(IProperty property) => Source.IsModified(property);
        public virtual bool IsStoreGenerated(IProperty property) => Source.IsStoreGenerated(property);
        public virtual void SetOriginalValue(IProperty property, object value) => Source.SetOriginalValue(property, value);
        public virtual void SetPropertyModified(IProperty property) => Source.SetPropertyModified(property);
        public virtual void SetStoreGeneratedValue(IProperty property, object value) => Source.SetStoreGeneratedValue(property, value);
        public virtual EntityEntry ToEntityEntry() => Source.ToEntityEntry();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no words. I'm searching how to increase bounty till 200.

Comment: You are welcome, glad being helpful :) It was really interesting challenge.

Comment: Next my EF question will have bounty 200 just because there is a chance to get answer from Ivan Stoev. We are very lucky with you.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to implement this in the EF Core 5.0? There is no SetCurrentValue method in IUpdateEntry interface any more.

Comment: @JonatanDragon Looks like it has ben renamed to `SetStoreGeneratedValue`. There are also some other changes that break the compilation. Posted the updated code, but just made it compile, I have no time for testing right now.

Comment: Great, thank you for your help. I did not expect such a quick reply. In the current state it throws: "Unable to cast object of type 'MyNamespace.AuditDeleteEntry' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry'." It looks like more has been changed in the internal EF 5.0 implementation.

Comment: @JonatanDragon Too bad. Why use interface if you expect to be implemented only by your specific class. These guys are breaking all OOP rules :-(

Comment: Haha, that's true. Anyway, thank you for your input :), I'll figure something out